# Creating a directory copying another directory's files into it, then creating a table in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a app that you can make a "channel" on, and I need to wonder if I can make it with PHP. Here is my code.

```
<?php

 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "channels");

if(isset($_POST['channel_name']) && $_POST['channel_name'] != "") {
   $dir = UUID();
   // I think channelname is an error as well.
   $channelname = $_POST['channel_name'];

   mkdir($dir, 0777, true);

   // I know there may be a syntax error in $index   
   $index = fopen($dir. "/index.php", "w");
   fclose($index);
   copy("index.php",$index);

   // Insert values into table
   $q = "INSERT INTO channels (dir, name) VALUES ($dir, $channelname)";
   $query = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
   if($query == true) {
   echo "your channel has been created";
   } else {
   echo "there was an error";
   };
 };

?>
```

Comment: You'd create the table in your script rather than phpmyadmin. What are you having troubles with?

Comment: I'm wpndering if this will work. Right now, my website is installing apps such as phpMyAdmin, so I can't access it yet.

Comment: Try without the SQL locally, or install mysql  locally. I did meant phpmyadmin wasn't needed right? Not sure why that delay is a rational for everyone else to parse your php.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.